# How to get version info from external file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Instead of manually editing the version info inside the IDE, is there a way to Delphi get this information from an external file ?

I'm trying to make an automated building system for my apps and the steps would be edit the version number, compile the project with *dcc32.exe* , sign the EXE and so on.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539316/how-can-i-read-details-of-file ?

Comment: You say you want to get it, but it then sounds like you instead want to set it. Which is it?

Comment: I think the question is clear, he wants to add the version info from an external source, not the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this, is by not using the Delphi Project Options. On the dialog of your screenshot, disable "Include version information in project". Remember to do this for all targets. I've struggled with conflicting settings between targets before, and typically got rid of the troubles by modifying the `.dproj` XML data manually.

Create an empty file with extension `.rc`, choose something different than your project name as file name. Then add the file with `Project > Add to project...`, you may have to change the file type to `Resource file (*.rc)`. It will add something to the `.dpr` file that looks like this:

```
{$R 'verinfo.res' 'verinfo.rc'}
```

Don't worry about the `.res` file, it will get generated by the compilation process based on your `.rc` file. (Actually it's [BRCC32.EXE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/BRCC32.EXE,_the_Resource_Compiler) that will get called to do this.)

Edit the `.rc` file and add a `VERSIONINFO` section, as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource). If you edit this file, or (re-)generate it by the automated building prior compilation, the resulting binaries should have this version data as official version by the file properties.

Comment: If you have _Project Magician_ installed and configured correctly, you can just set the version info in the base configuration without bothering the other configurations.
https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2018/05/17/keep-your-project-files-clean-with-project-magician/